# exec user process caused: exec format error on k3s

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, arm

I'm trying to deploy a Go project on my raspberry, but I have this famous error *standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error*.

I deploy my docker image with this :

```
FROM golang:1.14.12-buster as builder
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=arm
[...]
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build -o main .
```

and

```
FROM arm32v7/golang:1.14.12-alpine
ENTRYPOINT ["./main", "args"]
```

I can run a container on my raspberry (with a docker run myImage) but when i deploy it in a kubernetes cluster, my pod give me this error *standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error*.

Is there something to configure in my k3s cluster ?

This is the docker version command :

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.11
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        42e35e6
 Built:             Mon Jun  1 09:20:15 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm
 Experimental:      false
```

and k3s version :

```
sudo k3s kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.3+k3s3", GitCommit:"0e4fbfefe1dd8734756dfa4f9ab4fc89665cece4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-11-13T07:15:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm"}
```

Is someone have an idea on the means to resolve my error?

Comment: Your error is about architecture mismatch, have you tried setting `GOARM=7` ? It's unclear what is architecture on the k8s cluster, the raspberry is ARMv6  (A/A+/B/B+/Zero).

Comment: Hi, i try this but i have the same comportement .. i don't understand why it's ok with docker and ko with k3s

Comment: i try again with docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7 [...] --push but i have the same error

Comment: i progress .. i try to call a docker image with my script.
but this image on k3s give me the error whereas the image work

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: Sorry for the response time.
I didn't solve this problem but to allows me to continue my project, i didn't use multi stages Dockerfile.